# Querying different collations across linked servers - works one direction, not the other

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, sql-server-collation

I'm trying to query between 2 servers with different collations. One query works, the other doesn't. I want to know why.

ServerA is 2019 RTM using Latin1_General_BIN collation.
ServerB is 2016 SP1 using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation.

The linked server properties for both servers (the link to ServerB from ServerA and vice versa) are identical, including the '**Use Remote Collation**' setting, which is set to False. '**Collation Compatible**' is False, and '**Collation Name**' is blank.

When I run this query from ServerA I get the error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

```
SELECT Count(1)
FROM ServerA.DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
INNER JOIN ServerB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB On TableA.ID = TableB.ID;
```

However, when I run the same query from ServerB it returns without issue.

Please don't tell me to just use "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" in the query. I know that. My question isn't necessarily how to resolve the error, it's why running the same query on one server returns the error and not on the other server.

Comment: what are the datatypes of the two ID columns?

Comment: This article seems to be relevant: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/how-it-works-linked-servers-and-collation-compatibility/ba-p/315460

Comment: @lptr, in this case the ID columns are both varchar(20).